# How can I remove error of undeclared identifier error on foundry?

Tags: compiler-errors, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm new to foundry and learning test cases at the moment. After installing the package I did not make any changes so everything is exactly how it should be (according to me).
I'm following a youtube tutorial for testFail function and doing everything as shown in the video but I'm getting this error and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong and how I can resolve it.

This is the error I get when I run **forge test**

Compiler run failed:
Error (7576): Undeclared identifier.

```
        vm.expectRevert(stdError.arithmeticError);
```

(It's taking **stdError** as undeclared identiifer)

Here is the test file:

// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import {Test, console2} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {Counter} from "../src/Counter.sol";

contract CounterTest is Test {
Counter public counter;

```
function setUp() public {
    counter = new Counter();
}

function testInc() public {
    counter.inc();
    assertEq(counter.count(), 1);
}

function testFailDec() public {
    counter.dec();
}

function test_RevertWhen_DecUnderFlow() public {
    vm.expectRevert(stdError.arithmeticError);
    counter.dec();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `stdError` library from `forge-std` isn't imported.

You need to extend your import statement to include the `stdError`, like this:

```
import {Test, stdError} from "@forge-std/Test.sol";
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `import {Test, console2} from "forge-std/Test.sol"; import {Counter} from "../src/Counter.sol";`
Try importing the whole script :

```
   import "forge-std/Test.sol";
   import "../src/Counter.sol";
```

Normally test contract in test.sol provides all the essential functionality you need to get started writing tests. but try it though